# PostgreSQL rename attribute in jsonb field

Tags: json, postgresql, sql-update, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

In PostgreSQL 9.5, is there a way to rename an attribute in a jsonb field?

For example:

```json
{ "nme" : "test" }
```

should  be renamed to

```json
{ "name" : "test"}
```

Comment: Take a look at string replacement (https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/172601/41320)

Comment: similar question added https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59908676/write-a-postgresql-query-to-update-a-json-column/59908979#59908979

Answer (score 137, accepted):

In `UPDATE` use [delete (-) and concatenate (||) operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html), e.g.:

```
create table example(id int primary key, js jsonb);
insert into example values
    (1, '{"nme": "test"}'),
    (2, '{"nme": "second test"}');

update example
set js = js - 'nme' || jsonb_build_object('name', js->'nme')
where js ? 'nme'
returning *;

 id |           js            
----+-------------------------
  1 | {"name": "test"}
  2 | {"name": "second test"}
(2 rows)
```

Comment: In case somebody wonders, `returning *` is not mandatory for the query to work. It only causes a display (like a `select`) of all updated rows, that is, all rows.

Comment: @klin: I tried your query it works. But is there any way that we get ids in {} and not simply mentioned in double quotes?

http://rextester.com/HQS81928

Comment: @PranavUnde - please ask a new question with an appropriate example.

Comment: Its works fine, can you please tell how to update nested objects like {"skill":{"c":{"name":"C", "code":"c"}}}, how to update c attribute inside skill.

Comment: Found the solution, first add the object with new attribute and then remove the existing attribute. something like this.


    `update example SET js = JSONB_SET(js::JSONB, '{skill,c++}', js->'skill'->'c', true) where js->'skill' ? 'c';`



   `update example SET js = js#-'{skill, c}' where js->'skill' ? 'c';`

Comment: This is awesome, thanks! Here's an example with Rails ActiveRecord for anyone it may help: https://www.todayilearned.fyi/by/odlp/til-you-can-rename-postgresql-jsonb-attributes-in-a-query

Answer (score 30):

I used the following for handling nested attributes and skipping any json that doesn't use the old name:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET json_field_name = jsonb_set(json_field_name #- '{path,to,old_name}',
                                '{path,to,new_name}',
                                json_field_name#>'{path,to,old_name}')
WHERE json_field_name#>'{path,to}' ? 'old_name';
```

just for reference docs:

- `#-` Delete the field or element with specified path (for JSON arrays, negative integers count from the end)
  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE
- `#>`Get JSON object at the specified path https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE

Comment: That worked for me, although I messed up the first entry of `{path, to, old_name}` it didn't seem to affect the result and I still got the right thing

Comment: @MatheusFelipe, can you please help me.

I need to change LicenseDate to LicenseExpirationDate

UPDATE dbo."dcp_OrgLevelEntityItems" 
SET "Attributes" = jsonb_set("Attributes" => '{LicenseDate}', '{LicenseExpirationDate}')
WHERE "Id" = 1

Sample JSON - Column name is Attributes

{
  "Name": "LIC",
  "Street": 223871,
  "City": 59390,
  "LicenseDate": "01092019"
}

Answer (score 16):

This is an old question, but still comes up high in the search rankings for this particular task. One approach that isn't all that JSON-ey but can still be a decent solution (*if there is a minimal risk of key-naming collision*) is to handle the field as TEXT, do a replace (could be a regex too) and then cast back to JSON.

Something like this, borrowing @klin's setup:

```
CREATE TABLE example(id INT PRIMARY KEY, js JSONB);
INSERT INTO example VALUES
    (1, '{"nme": "test"}'),
    (2, '{"nme": "second test"}');

UPDATE EXAMPLE
SET js = (REPLACE(js::TEXT, '"nme"', '"name"'))::JSONB
RETURNING *;
```