# write a postgreSQL query to update a json column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table T with a column J of type json, and one of it's row contains value

```
{'SELECTION':'A'}
```

I want to change it to

```
{'selection':'A'}
```

i.e change the key of the JSON.

Any one has experience? I am not able to find any relevant resource.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL rename attribute in jsonb field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308764/postgresql-rename-attribute-in-jsonb-field)

Comment: let me try, actually my column type is json, not jsonb

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Sebastian, I solved it using the documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

```
update T set J = '{"selection":"A"}' where  J::jsonb @> '{"SELECTION":"A"}'::jsonb
```

Another query that will do same

```
update T set J = '{"selection":"A"}' where J::json->>'SELECTION'='A'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked well.

```
create table form
(
  id integer, 
  data json
);

insert into form (id, data) 
values (1000, 
    $$
      {"formType": "DEFAULT", "old_key": {"column": [{"old_key": "1"}, {"old_key": "7"}, {"old_key": "22"}]}}  
    $$::json    
  )
;

SELECT *
FROM form;

UPDATE form
set data = data::jsonb - 'old_key' || jsonb_build_object('new_key', data->'old_key')
where data::jsonb ? 'old_key';

SELECT *
FROM form;
```