# Update nested property in JSONB field in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have data structure like:

- `id bigint`
- `articles jsonb`

Example:

```
id: 1,
articles: {
  "1": {
    "title": "foo"
  },
  "2": {
    "title": "bar"
  }
}
```

I want to change field name of `title` (for example `articleTitle`). Is there any easy way to do that ?

Edit: I can do that with string replace, but can I do that operating on jsonb? Like using `jsonb_set()` ?

```
UPDATE person 
SET articles = replace(articles::TEXT,'"title":','"articleTitle":')::jsonb
```

Comment: Check this answer by @klin https://stackoverflow.com/a/42308902/1163424

Comment: Thanks, but in this case even deeper structure with an unknown number of articles.

Comment: you'll just need to run the same query for the number of article ids you'd like to rename